# How to Filter more than one field using WPF AutoCompleteBox

Tags: wpf, autocompletebox

i am trying to customize the suggestions on the AutoCompleteBox in the WPF Tool kit. Right now i have a last name field which when the user enters characters a query runs that retrieves the top 10 records based on that last name. i would also like to filter by first name, i tried splitting out the comma and searching by the last name and the characters entered in the first name.

however, as soon as a space or comma is entered into the autocompletebox, the suggest functionality stops working, which I believe is because the ValueMemberPath property is set to be last name. Is there a work around for this, or a way to modify the ValueMemberPath to handle multiple values? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wont get any satisfied answer there's a nice control that I'm using from codeproject that supports searching by keywords with easy API.

[WPFAutoCompleteTextbox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFAutoCompleteTextbox.aspx)

Comment: thank you! downloading the source code now, will check that out.

Comment: just wanted to stop back and say that this answer really helped me out. the source code is easy to understand and modify.

Comment: I'm really happy 4 u , Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

There's another simple way to get Autocompletebox accept more than one Property for filtering: just use ValueMemberBinding like this:

```
ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"
```

and define "myConverter" so that it concatenates your filter properties (properly separated) into a single string; now your AutocompleteBox will use the whole string as it was a single property.

Comment: What is `myConverter` ? can you explain how to define it ? i'm new to wpf. so unable to understand this.