# How to make WPF AutoCompleteBox accept more than one Property for filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, ivalueconverter, autocompletebox

I want to search in multiple fields in AutoCompleteBox, I want to search in **ClientName** if the user starts typing characters, and search in **ClientNumber** if the user starts typing numbers.

I searched on the internet and from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13566714/1890313) I understand that I should use **Converter** to accomplish what I want, But unfortunately, they do not explain how can I write the converter!

> This is the AutoCompleteBox

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="txbClientName" FilterMode="StartsWith" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ocClients}" 
        ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Converter= {StaticResource ClientSearch}}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=this,
        Path=ContactPerson,
        Mode=TwoWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" PreviewKeyUp="txbClientName_PreviewKeyUp" LostFocus="txbClientName_LostFocus">

        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <Label Content="{Binding ContactPerson}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
```

> What should the **ClientSearch** Converter do ??

```
public class ClientSearchConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //What should I write here !!!
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Any help, please!

Comment: IValueConverter takes value and parameter and returns back whatever you want it to return back. In your binding you are sending your ViewModel to the Converter, and you have it there as value. Cast value as the type of your ViewModel, and you have access to the ViewMode.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I received Client as value in IValueConverter and that is not helped me, I'm thinking that I should  received the first digit to check if this digit is character or number .. then I return the ValueMember ClientName or ClientNumber. I'm I right ?

Comment: I think you are doing it completely wrong. Your ValueMemberBinding should be bound to the Property you want to search in, and you can send your Client as ConverterParameter, then you can compare any property of parameter to the Value you are typing

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Thanks for your reply, but I’m really confused.. can you explain in detail please.